# what is the best algorithm to find the best count same number of digit?

Tags: database, algorithm, digit

I want to know the best algorithm to find row in DB have the best count for  same number in each digit.

For example
there is five-digit number consist of 1 or 2.

11221 is standard

in DB column

11222 -> 4 hit -> the best count

12211 -> 2 hit

11111 -> 3 hit

22222 -> 2 hit

21212 -> 2 hit

12121 -> 3 hit

.
   .
   .

more information )

This is for matching same selection each users.

So If one user db column will update 1 -> 12 -> 122 -> 1222 -> 12221 ->... by processing selection.

and find user column to have the best count same numbers for each digit.

I want to know this method algorithm or another method.

Comment: Is it [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) the one you are after (and don't know how is it named)?

Comment: They're all table scans -- after that, it doesn't much matter.